# Inequality with $ax^2+bx+c$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $a,b,c,x,y > 0$  reals prove that:
$$(ax^2+bx+c)(ay^2-by+c) \geq (4ac-b^2)xy$$
What I have done is this:
$$ax^2+bx+c=a \left (x+\frac{b}{2a} \right)^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}$$
$$ay^2-by+c=a \left (y-\frac{b}{2a} \right)^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}$$
From here I have two cases:
$  4ac-b^2 >0$
$$\left[ \sqrt{a}^2 \left (x+\frac{b}{2a} \right)^2+\sqrt \frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}^2\right ]\cdot \left[ \sqrt{a}^2 \left (y-\frac{b}{2a} \right)^2+\sqrt \frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}^2\right ]\geq$$
$$\left [ \sqrt a \left (x+\frac{b}{2a} \right)\cdot\sqrt \frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}+  \sqrt a \left (y-\frac{b}{2a} \right)\cdot\sqrt \frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}\right ]^2$$
This is just Cauchy.
$$\left[ \sqrt{a}^2 \left (x+\frac{b}{2a} \right)^2+\sqrt \frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}^2\right ]\cdot \left[ \sqrt{a}^2 \left (y-\frac{b}{2a} \right)^2+\sqrt \frac{4ac-b^2}{4a}^2\right ]\geq$$
$$a \cdot \frac{4ac-b^2}{4a} \left ( x+\frac{b}{2a}+y-\frac{b}{2a} \right )^2=(4ac-b^2) \left ( \frac{x+y}{2}\right )^2\geq (4ac-b^2)xy. $$
Now the second case I have trouble proving : $4ac-b^2 < 0$.
If someone can take a look and give me a solution or a hint I would much appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Use AM-GM inequality to obtain
$$
ax+b+\frac{c}{x}\ge b+2\sqrt{ac},
$$
$$
ay-b+\frac{c}{y}\ge -b+2\sqrt{ac}.
$$

Comment: Yes. I have tried this too. But it's true only if $4ac-b^2>0$. And I don't know what to do if $4ac-b^2<0$

Comment: @ovetz13 Umm... the given inequality seems to fail if $4ac-b^2< 0$. Look at the example: $(a,b,c)=(1,3,1)$. Then for $(x,y)=(3,1)$, the LHS becomes $-19$ while the RHS is $-15$. It fails to hold $-19\geqslant -15$.

Comment: So I can say that the given inequality is true only if $4ac-b^2>0$. Problem solved I guess.

Comment: @ovetz13 Yep, I think so.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong.

Try $b=c=1$, $x=1$, $y=3$ and $a=\frac{1}{3}.$

Comment: I know. Thank you.